# Computer gets stuck when going to sleep

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep

Whenever my Windows 7 laptop goes to sleep (either by automatically going to sleep automatically or by telling it to) it gets stuck.

It doesn't go into sleep mode, the screen goes black and it shows no disc activity from the light on the front, but the power LED stays solid green and not orange glowing like it normally does. I can't get it out of this state except by holding down the power button for 10 seconds and starting it back up again.

Recently I updated my graphics card drivers but I wouldn't imagine that updating would cause this issue.

I checked the windows event log and it reveals nothing relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all peripherals are unplugged first, then attempt to sleep mode, if it does not work, roll back the driver update.

On a vista machine I have I recently came to the same issue, I had installed a USB ethernet adapters drivers on the machine since I was unable to use the ethernet port built in, after I did this, I found I could not go to sleep mode (hybrid sleep) so I uninstalled the drivers and it worked fine.

If you are using hybrid sleep, this is the most likely reason as it seems to not agree with updating drivers/installing new ones.

Answer (score 2):

I would try a couple of things: 
Update the BIOS
Run Memtest from a Boot CD to see what's going on with your RAM.

I have had this happen to me only to find out it was RAM issue.

Comment: I've also seen this happen with outdated/corrupted chipset drivers.